# How do I change the initial view controller programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to lead the user directly to the main page of my application if they are logged in (checked using user defaults).

However, it will stay at the screen I chose as the initial view controller in the storyboard no matter what. This is my didFinishLaunchingWithOptions function in the AppDelegate file:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        
        
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        print(NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true))
        if UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "userEmail") != nil {
            self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TabBarController")
            let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: initialViewController)
            self.window?.rootViewController = navigationController
            self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

        }
        return true
    }
```

Comment: Do you also have a SceneDelegate in your project?

Comment: Yes, I do have one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From iOS 13 on, the responsibilites of `AppDelegate` have been split between `AppDelegate` and `SceneDelegate`. In particular, `SceneDelegate` is where you want to present a `UIViewController`.

Remove the `if` block of your code from `AppDelegate` and add it to `wilConnectTo` of `SceneDelegate`, like this:

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
    
    guard let windowScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }

    if UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "userEmail") != nil {
        self.window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(identifier: "TabBarController")
        let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: initialViewController)
        self.window?.rootViewController = navigationController
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
}
```

On a side note, if you're supporting iOS versions lower than 13.0, then you need to use `AppDelegate` also. This is where the `available` operator comes handy.

Comment: You're welcome. I had forgotten to add the if check, I've edited the answer now. Please notice this.

Comment: Yep no worries! I included the if check when you posted your original answer.

Comment: Also, if you want to support iOS 12 or below, then you also need to use AppDelegate and use the available operator.